# svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'main'; please relocate

Tags: apache, svn, webdav

I have problem with my own Subversion repository. It worked yesterday. But I received an error when I was adding new file today:

> svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'main'; please relocate

List of my actions:

1. /home/user/test# svn checkout https://website.biz/repo/siteweb.com

   OK
2. /home/user/test/siteweb.com/trunk# touch 1.txt

   OK
3. /home/user/test/siteweb.com/trunk# svn add 1.txt
4. /home/user/test/siteweb.com/trunk# svn -m "adding 1.txt " commit

   ```
   Adding         trunk/1.txt

   svn: Commit failed (details follow):
   svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'main'; please relocate
   svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'main'; please relocate
   ```

What is this, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'something'; please relocate

It is a lame misconfiguration issue! You probably use dav_svn module to access your SVN repository. And there is global redirection on the ErrorDocument directive in your web server config. You should override this setting for the SVN repository section in the dav_svn config.

Edit the following file: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf`, add the directive "ErrorDocument 404 default" between Location lines. It does the trick. My config can be an example for you:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn-repos/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
  ErrorDocument 404 default
</Location>
```

And reload the web server config with the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: Do you mean /etc/init.d/apache2ctl restart?

Comment: is the directive ErrorDocument 404 default compatible with Apache 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this exception while fetching it from a client, either a command line client or tigris, it may be the url pattern. For example,

http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate will work if you replace viewvc with svnroot such as

https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate

Comment: For me, it was to replace your 'svnroot' with just 'svn' as follows:
https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svn/nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/36181-quot-Repository-moved-temporarily.-Please-Relocate-quot-Er), there seems to be a pre-commit hook that sends this message (btw this is the first hit when I ask google for *svn Repository moved temporarily to 'main'*).

Unless **you** added this hook (assuming you're the only administrator of https://website.biz/repo/siteweb.com), you might be in serious trouble...

On the other hand, it could also be an apache configuration issue. In that case, I assume that my linked thread will help you too.

Comment: Thanks. But there are templates only. 
post-commit.tmpl  post-revprop-change.tmpl  pre-commit.tmpl  pre-revprop-change.tmpl  start-commit.tmpl
post-lock.tmpl    post-unlock.tmpl          pre-lock.tmpl    pre-unlock.tmpl

Comment: @dba.in.ua: did you read the full thread? they are talking about apache configuration issues too...

Answer (score 0):

This error might also be caused by a misconfigured client.

It happened to me because I had spaces, not commas, in `http_proxy_exceptions` in `~/.subversion/servers`.

```
http_proxy_exceptions = *.foo.com *.bar.com
```

was incorrect, but

```
http_proxy_exceptions = *.foo.com, *.bar.com
```

worked. (The first form may have worked in the past.)

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when a proxy server was added

[image]