# Strange error while trying to clone a SVN repo via git

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I tried to clone the repository of the Linux Libertine project. It is a SVN repo, but I wanted to use git as my personal backend. Now, I got a strange error message:

```
$ git svn clone -s  http://linuxlibertine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/robert/svnroot/.git/
Repository has been moved: Repository moved temporarily to 'http://linuxlibertine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot'; please relocate at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 1923
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251587/svn-repository-moved-temporarily-to-main-please-relocate (the issue is with svn.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you use actually suffers from a redirection loop (you can check it with your browser).

However, according to the [develop page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/develop) of the project on SourceForge, you're not using the correct URL: you should use `http://linuxlibertine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/linuxlibertine` instead.

```
$ git svn clone -s http://linuxlibertine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/linuxlibertine
```